# Null Pointer Exception - BaseAdapter notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, filter, baseadapter

I am trying to implement Filterable `ListView` but getting `NPE`:

```
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.ActorsActivity$ActorAdapter.getCount(ActorsActivity.java:252)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:804)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6545)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.wingnity.jsonparsingtutorial.ActorsActivity$ActorAdapter$ItemFilter.publishResults(ActorsActivity.java:237)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
08-13 11:34:20.980: E/AndroidRuntime(31796):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is where i am facing issue:

```
 @Override
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
       FilterResults results) {
       actorsList  = (ArrayList<Actors>) results.values; // Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<Actors>
       notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

I am getting data into ListView but facing this error while i am entering text into EditText...

**Activity code:**

```
public class ActorsActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;   
ActorAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
EditText editSearch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editSearch);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();

    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors");

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), actorsList.get(position).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();              
        }
    });

    editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}


class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActorsActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    actor.setCountry(object.getString("country"));

                    actorsList.add(actor);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        dialog.cancel();

        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);          
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


public class ActorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private ItemFilter itemFilter;
    ArrayList<Actors> filteredItems;

    public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> arrayList) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorsList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;            
        if (view == null) {             
            holder = new ViewHolder();                          
            view = inflater.inflate(Resource, null);

            holder.tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.tvCountry = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvName.setText(actorsList.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvCountry.setText(actorsList.get(position).getCountry());

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvCountry;      
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Actors> filterList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filteredItems.size(); i++) {

                    Actors actors = filteredItems.get(i);
                    String name = actors.getName().toUpperCase();
                    String country = actors.getCountry().toUpperCase();
                    if (name.contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()) || country.contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        filterList.add(actors);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = filteredItems.size();
                results.values = filteredItems;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            actorsList  = (ArrayList<Actors>) results.values; // Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<Actors>
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

 public Filter getFilter() {
     if (itemFilter == null) {
         itemFilter = new ItemFilter();
     }
     return itemFilter;
 }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return actorsList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return actorsList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
  }

}
```

So **how can i resolve this issue ?** I am not getting why i am facing this.

Comment: check actorsList size > 0 or != null something because you are not getting any value there

Comment: i am getting data into listview..  but facing this error when writing text on search field

Comment: `filteredItems` are null since i dont see any `filteredItems = ...`

Comment: so what i have to do to resolve this issue ? @pskink

Comment: i have no idea what you want: to filter existing list or show the items from some web api based on what you type or anything else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized `filteredItems` that's why you get `NPE` in `publishResults()` function. You have to initialize first in your constructor

```
public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> arrayList) {
    // your code
    actorsList = arrayList;
    filteredItems=arrayList; //initially show all items 
}
```

Now you have to use `filteredItems` in all other functions (like `getCount(), getView()`... etc.) inplace of `actorsList` so that your listview show only filtered items and in `performFiltering()` change

```
for (int i = 0; i < filteredItems.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < actorsList .size(); i++)
```

also remove `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` as you have not make any change in Arraylist after assigning it to adapter.

Comment: thanks filteredItems = arrayList; //initially show all items worked for me.

Comment: I have to show youtube playlist into listview.. can you help me in that ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused because you are trying to change the list of displayed values from inside the Adapter. Building the views the adapter does not find some values to notify and causes the NullPointerException. Try to filter your list outside the adapter. You could implement the filter independently from adapter in his own class in an object oriented way. So in the text listener you can do the filter in a separate step, 2nd step should be to assign the values to your actorList and 3rd to notify the adapter. Should look like this

```
editSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        //change the values, DO NOT create new because the reference will change
        actorsList = myFilter.filter(s); //assign the filtered values, myFilter could be static function also
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```